# Tail of an array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

In powershell I can get the tail of an array by doing this:

```
$array = 1..10
$tail = $array[-($array.Length-1)..-1]
```

I am correctly getting the tail of the array, i.e.,

2,3,4,...9,10

Is this the best I can do?
Is there a better looking alternative?

Comment: As an aside: [GitHub issue #7940](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7940) is a long-standing _feature request_ that would simplify your example to: `$array[1..]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select-Object -Last` is the easiest option in my opinion:

```bash
$array | Select-Object -Last 9 # last 9 elements from the array
```

You can also use `-Skip`:

```bash
$array | Select-Object -Skip 1 # skip the first element
```

However you should be aware that both alternatives, *indexing* as in your question and `Select-Object` will end up creating a new array and can add overhead to your code. If you need to perform this operation many times, the recommended approach is an [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=net-8.0):

```bash
$array = 1..10
$segment = [System.ArraySegment[int]]::new($array)
$segment.Slice(1)                     # from index 1 till the end
$segment.Slice(1, $segment.Count - 3) # 7 elements starting from index 1
```

The `.Slice` method outputs an `ArraySegment<T>` making it very efficient, then if you need to materialize that slice you can call its [`.ToArray()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1.toarray?view=net-8.0#system-arraysegment-1-toarray).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$null` to capture the first element on assignment, then store the rest in `$tail` like so:

```
$null, $tail = $array
```

Comment: nice! I wish I could accept 2 answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that the `1` in `$array.Length-1` should be dynamic like:

```
$Skip = 1
$array[-($array.Length-$Skip)..-1]
```

You could also change this to:

```
$array[$Skip..($array.Length-1)]
```

And knowing that PowerShell isn't strict by default (meaning unless you do something like [`Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)), you might even do something like this:

```
$Array[$Skip..9999]
```

Comment: thanks for pointing in the direction of strict mode - I did not know about this, and took the default behaviour for granted and invariable!